# Uppercase numbers in section headers - classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, classicthesis, small-caps, oldstylenums

How can I force an uppercase number in the subsection header of `classicthesis`? As oldstyle numbers are used through `classicthesis`, this causes a problem for headers where abbreviations containing numbers are used. For the `section` headers, this isn't a problem as small caps are used.

[image: Small caps section header]

But for `subsection` and below, normal size font is used. For this, abbreviations containing numbers don't look right.

[image: Normal text subsection header]

How can I force this 0 to be an uppercase number?

EDIT: I'm using pdftex to compile.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\chapter{A}
Text
\section{TAAR13c}
Text
\subsection{TMD0 interface mutants}
Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `xelatex` or  `lualatex` use

```
\chapter{A}
Text
\section[TAAR\liningnums{13}c]{TAAR13c}
Text
\subsection{TMD\liningnums{0} interface mutants}
Text
```

For `pdflatex` you can define a command `\liningnums{...}`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using pdftex, so unfortunately those suggestions don't work. How can I define a command to do that for pdftex?

Comment: define: `\def\liningnumbers#1{{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont#1}}` and then use for example: `\liningnumbers{01234567890}`

Comment: Great, works like a charm – thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your font is MinionPro, which means that the MinionPro package is loaded. Therefore, you can use \figureversion{lf} to change from text figures to lining figures:

```
\subsection{\figureversion{lf}TMD0 interface mutants}
```

Your MWE does not load [MinionPro](https://ctan.org/pkg/minionpro), but I assume you do that in the "real" source file. If you do not have [MinionPro](https://ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) installed, you can load the package [fontaxes](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontaxes) instead, which worked perfectly on my system with the Palatino font `classicthesis` uses as standard font.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
% \usepackage{MiniorPro}        %% <- Load MinionPro to get access to \figureversion
\usepackage{fontaxes}           %% <- or fontaxes, which works with Palatino, 
                                %%    if you do not have MinioPro installed
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\chapter{A}
Text
\section{TAAR13c}
Text
\subsection{\figureversion{lf}TMD0 interface mutants}   %% <- With \figureversion
\subsection{TMD0 interface mutants}                     %% <- Without \figureversion
Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The figure version command seems to work i.e. there is no error, but it doesn't change anything – what should it do?

Comment: @anothersimonharris It seems that you have to load the package `minionpro` explicitly. At least, if I did, it worked, but I have installed that font. If you do not have `minionpro`, you can use `fontaxes`see updated MWE.